# procedimiento almacenado en sequelize datos en null

Tags: mysql, nodejs, sequelize

tengo un procedimiento almacenado el cual me funciona bien en sql workbench, así es como llamo al procedimiento

```
SET @p0 = '4';
CALL mydb.dashboard(@p0);
```

Este es el resultado (por razones de protección de datos borro algunos datos en la imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En sequelize así llamo al procedimiento

```
const queryDashboard = [
            'SET @p0 = 4;',
            'CALL dashboard(@p0);'
        ].join('');

const InformeDashboard = await dashboard.query(queryDashboard, { raw: true })
```

Este es el resultado

```
[
    {
      location: '',
      device: '',
      datetime: null,
      formatdate: null,
      PH: null,
      ORP: null,
      NIVEL: null,
      rssi: null,
      CE: null,
      TEMP: null,
      idEmpresa: 4,
      flag: null
    },
    {
      location: '',
      device: '',
      datetime: null,
      formatdate: null,
      PH: null,
      ORP: null,
      NIVEL: null,
      rssi: null,
      CE: null,
      TEMP: null,
      idEmpresa: 4,
      flag: null
    },
    {
      location: '',
      device: '',
      datetime: null,
      formatdate: null,
      PH: null,
      ORP: null,
      NIVEL: null,
      rssi: null,
      CE: null,
      TEMP: null,
      idEmpresa: 4,
      flag: null
    }
  ],
```

Nuevamente por protección de datos borro los resultados de 'location' y 'device' y agreso solo 3 resultados para que poder publicar la pregunta

Mi pregunta es ¿por qué al llamar al procedimiento desde sequelize me devuelve los datos en null?

Gracias

Comment: Pero la primera y de la tercera a la sexta filas de tu consulta devuelven los resultados similares a los que aparecen en tu JSON (donde todos los datos son NULL, salvo "idEmpresa", y "location" y "device" que están ocultos adrede). ¿Cuál es realmente el problema? Por cierto, ten siempre presente que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Comment: ¿Tiene configurada la opción `multipleStatements` en las opciones personalizadas `dialectOptions` en el constructor Sequelize?. Si la activa, tenga cuidado con los ataque de inyección SQL. Vea [Dialect-Specific Things](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/).

Comment: @wchiquito  muchas gracias, si tengo activado la opción multipleStatements, gracias